# How to encode array of bytes in PHP

Tags: php, c++, arrays, base64, encode

I am trying to encode an array of bytes in PHP, and decode it to byte array (ACE_Byte* = unsigned char*) using C++ with ACE, so far without success. My guess is that the encoding in PHP doesn't work well, since the decode is plain and simple:
I tried the encoding below without success.
Can anybody help me find a good way to encode?

```
/// Encoding in PHP
public function EncodeArray(){
        $myArray = array();
        $myArray[0] = 'A';
        $myArray[1] = 'B';
        $myArray[2] = 'C';
        $myArray[3] = 15;           
        $myArray[4] = 250;  

        //First try
        $serialized = serialize($myArray); 
        $mySerializedString = base64_encode($serialized);
        return $mySerializedString;

        //Second try
        $imploded = implode($myArray);
        $myImplodedString = base64_encode($imploded);
        return $myImplodedString;

        //Third try         
        $packed = pack('C*',$myArray);
        $myPackedString = base64_encode ($packed);
        return $myPackedString;
}

///Decoding in C++ using ACE library    
bool DecodeString(std::string& myString)        
{
    size_t uiLength;
    const ACE_Byte* p_myArray =  ACE_Base64::decode((const ACE_Byte*)myString.c_str(),&uiLength);
    if(p_myArray == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Unlike C 'A' in php doesn't denote a char/byte but a string. Also regading $myArray[4]=250, when you pass $myArray to anything that treats the elements as strings - like implode() -  250 will be converted into the string `250`, not a single byte. [implode()](http://docs.php.net/implode) takes two parameters; in your case the first one should be `''` - an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.
It was, as @VolkerK mentioned (Thanks for that!) - using string instead of a char.
In addition, the use of the pack should have been different:

```
/// Encoding in PHP
public function EncodeArray(){
    $myArray = array();
    $myArray[0] = ord('A'); //or a number, like: 0x40;
    $myArray[1] = ord('B');
    $myArray[2] = ord('C');
    $myArray[3] = 15;           
    $myArray[4] = 250;  
    $Length = 5;            

    for($i = 0; $i < $Length; $i++)
    {
        //concat the string
        $myPackedString = $myPackedString . pack('C',$myArray[$i]); 
    }

    $myPackedString = base64_encode ($myPackedString);
    return $myPackedString;
}
```

Comment: or `return base64_encode('ABC'.chr(15).chr(250));` same result: `QUJDD/o=` ;-)

Comment: Thanks @VolkerK, my actual string is much longer than that, and more complex, so this concatenation won't be too great in my code...